# simplify function to a single return statement

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused as I was asked to simplify this function down to a single return statement, and I'm not exactly sure how I would do that as I'm not sure what the paradigm is for angular / typescript with this.

```
  get remainingSpend() {
    if (this.spend >= 0) {
      if (this.spend- this.organization.total <= 0) {return '';}

      return this.spend - this.organization.total;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Angular and TypeScript aren't relevant here, it's just JS and logic. A basic recommendation would be to write a few unit tests for the current implementation, to help understand the current behaviour and prevent regressions, then refactor.

Comment: I'm assuming a ternary operator and inverting the second if makes the most sense then?

Comment: Did you try that? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get remainingSpend() {
  return (this.spend >= 0 && this.spend > this.organization.total) ?
    this.spend - this.organization.total : ''
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like so:

```
get remainingSpend(){
   return this.spend < 0 || this.spend <= this.organization.total ? '' 
       : this.spend - this.organization.total
}
```